# Noetherian normal ring is a finite direct product of normal domains

Tags: commutative-algebra, noetherian

> Let $A$ be a Noetherian normal ring, that is, the localization of $A$ at every prime is a normal domain. I want to show $A$ is a finite product of normal domains.

If $p_1,\ldots,p_n$ are the minimal primes of $A$, I can show 
$$A \cong A/p_1 \times \cdots \times A/p_n.$$
However why should each $A/p_i$ be a normal domain? I can't seem to see why this is true. I need to see why given any prime $p \supseteq p_i$, $(A/p_i)_p = A_p /{p_i}_p$ is normal. Why should a quotient of a normal domain be normal?

Comment: Look at the minimal primes in $A_p$...

Answer (score 0):

You know that $A\simeq A_1\times\cdots\times A_n$ with $A_i$ integral domains. Let $m_i$ be a maximal ideal of $A_i$. Then $M_i=A_1\times\cdots\times m_i\times\cdots\times A_n$ is a maximal ideal of $A$ and $A_{M_i}\simeq A_{i_{m_i}}$, so $A_{i_{m_i}}$ is a normal domain. Can you prove now that $A_i$ is normal?

> If not, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/429368/normal-at-every-localization-implies-normal?rq=1).